# CSS: hide table with no class or id

Tags: html, css, html-table

Is there a way to hide a particular table that does not have a class by using the table styling to select?

For example if I had a table with this name

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="300" height="100">
```

or

```
<td colspan="3">
```

I do not have access to the html and cannot use javascript, must be a css solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to sacrifice IE 6 compatibility, you can to it based on attributes with the [attribute selector](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selector_attribute.html). For example:

```
td[colspan="2"] {color: red}
table[border="0"][cellspacing="0"][cellpadding="0"][width="300"][height="100"] {text-align: center}
```

Otherwise, you could try to select the table based on the context (e.g. `div.container div.innercontainer table`).

Answer (score 2):

Do all other tables have any classes? If yes, you could hide ALL tables and display only the ones with classes:

```
table { dispaly: none; }
table.someClass1,
table.someClass2 { display: table; }
```

Keep in mind, this will hide ALL tables and display ONLY the ones that you specify in the clause with "display: table".

Answer (score 1):

You can use a contextual selector to specify exactly which `<table>` you want to hide according to it's parent elements (given it is unique enough in the markup from other `<table>`s):

So if you have:

```
<div><p><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="300" height="100"></table></p></div>
```

Then you can do:

```
div p table {
    display: none;
}
```

Compatible on most modern browsers (including IE6).

Comment: this is by far the most relevant answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can apply rules using attrbutes. Combined with contextual selectors it can solve your problem:

```
div#page-foo div.bar td[colspan=3] {
  display: none;
}
```