# How to hide paragraph having no class using css?

Tags: css

I am having dynamic pages and contains div and paragraph like this for example:

```
<div class="oe_view_nocontent">
    <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
        Click to add a contact in your contacts directory.
    </p>
    <p>
        Odoo helps you easily track all activities related to
        a customer: discussions, history of business opportunities,
        documents, etc.
    </p>
</div>
```

What i am trying is show only that paragraph which has **class="oe_view_nocontent"** and hide the other one who has no class.

I tried to sort out by using these threads:

[Hide long text except the first two paragraphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958012/hide-long-text-except-the-first-two-paragraphs)

[CSS: hide table with no class or id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560311/css-hide-table-with-no-class-or-id)

I tried:

```
p {
    display: none;
}
p.oe_view_noontent {
  display: div;
}
```

and from here:
[Can I write a CSS selector selecting elements NOT having a certain class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110300/can-i-write-a-css-selector-selecting-elements-not-having-a-certain-class)

My try:

```
p:not(.class) {
    display: none;
}
```

But i am not getting anything. I just want that

who has

> class="oe_view_nocontent_create"

Any idea where i am doing mistake?

Comment: `:not(.class)` means elements not having the class `class`. If you want them not to have the attribute `class`, use the attribute selector. `:not([class])`.

Comment: did you try p:not(:class) or p:not(.oe_view_nocontent_create)

Comment: p:not(.oe_view_nocontent_create) works fine - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/rPqXjV

Comment: Oh yes it works. Thanks

Comment: @user3162878, posted comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posted comment as answer

```css
p:not(.oe_view_nocontent_create) {
  display:none
}
```

```html
<div class="oe_view_nocontent">
    <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
        Click to add a contact in your contacts directory.
    </p>
    <p>
        Odoo helps you easily track all activities related to
        a customer: discussions, history of business opportunities,
        documents, etc.
    </p>
</div>
```

codepen -  codepen.io/nagasai/pen/rPqXjV

Answer (score 2):

I think, you are looking for `not:() selector`.

```
p:not(.oe_view_nocontent_create) {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: yep thnx. This has been answered by Naga Sai

Comment: ohh. i didnt notice that :)